# Saving multiple images in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to save multiple image using this code. But instead its saving all the files including video,thumbnail and image. All i need to do is to save the images only. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

```
    List<string> img = new List<string>();
                HttpFileCollection httpFileCollection = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < httpFileCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = httpFileCollection[i];
                    if (httpPostedFile.ContentLength > 0  && httpPostedFile.ContentType.StartsWith("image/"))
                    {
                        httpPostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Icon/") + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(httpPostedFile.FileName));
                        img.Add(Server.MapPath("~/Icon/") + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(httpPostedFile.FileName));
                    }
                    
                }

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageURL", img.ToArray().Length > 0 ? String.Join(",", img.ToArray()) : Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Comment: You never check if a file is an image. You call httpPostedFile.SaveAs for all files

Comment: try to add another statement in `if(httpPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)` which will check if file is an image

Comment: I have edited the code as per suggestions and help. But now the problem is that the data is not seperated by comma in the same row. It is instead saving each image path in a new row. How can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never checks the type of the image and saves all files. You can detect images by checking the ContentType field or the extension of the file, eg.

```
HttpFileCollection httpFileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < httpFileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = httpFileCollection[i];
    if (httpPostedFile.ContentLength > 0 
       && httpPostedFile.ContentType.StartsWith("image/"))
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean that now the images are coming but they are not seperated by commas instead every new image is coming in a new line. See the updated code that I am using now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check the file extension if you know that images are always going to be from safe source

```
HttpFileCollection httpFileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < httpFileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = httpFileCollection[i];
    string fileNameExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName);
    if (httpPostedFile.ContentLength > 0 &&  fileNameExtension ==".Jpg")
    {
         ...
    }
}
```